# jQuery set width of a children img for a parent div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to set width of a wrapper, so paragraph will be not wider than the image using jQuery. What mistake I made?

```js
$(function(){

$('.wrapper').css({
    width: $(this).children('img').width(),
});

});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/200"/>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/500/500"/>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/300/300"/>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you have the element with the `module` class?

Comment: thanks, corrected. Still doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your code is that you're updating all the `.wrapper` elements at the same time, and also `this` in the `css()` method will refer to the `document`, not the `.wrapper` element.

There is also the additional problem that the images may not have loaded yet so they will have a width of `0` until that time.

To do what you require hook a `load` event handler to the `img` elements and set the width of the sibling `p` element from there:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wrapper img').on('load', function() {
    $(this).next('p').width($(this).width());
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/200" />
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/500/500" />
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/300/300" />
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it works only until you refresh website. After that cleaning cache is needed. At least on Safari

Comment: found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached